# CORS error when loading Stripe checkout form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, stripe-payments

I'm getting a CORS error when trying to redirect to the Stripe component.

### Checkout page

```
<%= form_with scope: :upgrade, url: upgrades_path do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :plan, value: "price_xxxxxx" %>
   <div class="card-btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Upgrade</button>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

### upgrades_controller.rb

```
def create
  session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
    line_items: [{
      price: strong_params[:plan],
      quantity: 1,
     }],
     mode: 'subscription',
     success_url: subscribed_upgrades_url,
     cancel_url: cancelled_upgrades_url,
    })

    redirect_to session.url, status: 303, allow_other_host: true
end
```

#### initializers/cors.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'https://checkout.stripe.com'
    resource '/upgrades',
      :headers => :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

Am seeing this error:

```
upgrades:1 Access to fetch at 'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1lErANbYzMDNmAbwfiliytAjAmVeNez4dzJVIBxetc..etc' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/upgrades') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How do I get past this error?

Comment: Your code looks fine for the most part. I wonder if there's anything funky going on with `cors` gem configuration. Can you try testing the route using your terminal as shown here [1]. another thing I'd try is changing the origins to wildcard `*` just to check if that solves it. 

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#redirect-customers:~:text=show%20in%20Checkout.-,Test,-your%20endpoint%20by

Comment: Thanks @hanzo I tried the wildcard on the origins and resource but it didn't help. The terminal test doesn't work as the auth token has not been provided.

Answer (score 2):

I could only get this to work by using a link to the `GET#new` action instead of submitting a form.

#### Checkout page

```
<%= link_to 'Upgrade', new_upgrade_path(upgrade: { plan: 'price_xxxxx' }), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

#### upgrades_controller.rb

```
def new
  session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
      line_items: [{
        price: strong_params['plan'],
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      mode: 'subscription',
      success_url: subscribed_upgrades_url,
      cancel_url: cancelled_upgrades_url,
    })

  redirect_to session.url
end

private

    def strong_params
      params
        .require(:upgrade)
        .permit(:plan)
    end
```

The `rack-cors` gem was no longer needed.